# Cambiar el idioma en APK compatible con versiones 2.X

Tags: android

Necesito cambiar el idioma de mi app, es decir, tengo un activity donde tengo un listado de los idiomas por escoger. Cuando selecciono uno me lo cambia, pero estoy usando unos métodos que solo se pueden usar con `android KItKat` 4.2 en adelante y quiero que se pueda usar a partir de 2.3. Aquí les dejo el código:

```
public void cargarLocale() {
    String PrefIdioma = "idioma";
    String idioma = leePreferencias (PrefIdioma, this);
    cambiarLocale(idioma);
}
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public void cambiarLocale(String locale) {
    //Si está vacío, queda el idioma por defecto del dispositivo
    if (Objects.equals(locale, ""))
        return;
    //Configuramos el idioma cargado desde SharedPreferences
    Locale miLocale = new Locale(locale);
    Locale.setDefault(miLocale);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
    config.locale = miLocale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

y el método que me selecciona el idioma es el siguiente:

```
findViewById(R.id.ingles).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String nuevoLocale = "";
            nuevoLocale = "en";
            Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "Selected English language !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            salvarLocale(nuevoLocale);
        }
    });

public void salvarLocale(String locale) {        
    String PrefIdioma = "idioma";
    salvaPreferencias(PrefIdioma, locale, this);       
    Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()                .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    finish();
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Me pregunto porque esa decisión de bajar tanto la versión mínima de la Api?  te dejo los ultimos datos de uso de versiones de android. http://www.xatakandroid.com/mercado/1-de-cada-10-dispositivos-android-ya-estan-actualizados-a-marshmallow

Comment: El problema es que mi pais hay muchas personas aun tienen dispositivos con android 2.3 por eso es que quiero disminuar el api para que mi apk pueda ser utilizadas por mas personas, sin importar su nivel economico.

Comment: No estoy en contra de tu opinión, pero quería informarte de que muchas aplicaciones dejarán de dar soporte a las versiones 2.x a finales de este año, entre ellas WhatsApp. Te lo digo, por que posiblemente no te compensa el esfuerzo extra para ser compatibles con todas las versiones para tener que modificarla a final de año. Por mucho que en tu país haya muchos dispositivos con versiones tan inferiores no superan el 2.1%. Como desarrollador, tienes que preguntarte, si realmente vale la pena llegar a esas versiones, por tu trabajo, por la vida útil de esas versiones y por la seguridad de tu app.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un dilema el cual tienen muchos desarrolladores que soportan API anteriores (y muy anteriores hehe), en cuanto a los métodos no soportados supongo te refieres a Objects.equals() :

> Call requires API level 19 (current min is 9):
>   java.util.Objects#equals less

Me parece que lo tienes solucionado, únicamente agregas la anotación al método que dentro usa `Objects.equals()`:

```
   @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
   public void cambiarLocale(String locale) {
          ...
          ...
   }
```

La anotación `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)` se usa para que este método sea compatible con versiones anteriores a Android API 19 (KitKat).

Si continuas con problemas te sugiero valides de esta forma:

```
public void cambiarLocale(String locale) {
    //Si está vacío, queda el idioma por defecto del dispositivo
    //if (Objects.equals(locale, ""))
    if (locale.equals(""))
       return;
...
...
```

ya que `locale` es un valor tipo `String`, de esta forma no necesitas  `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)` .

Comment: Cuando lo pruebo en un dispositivo con android 4.1 se cierra y me marca en esa linea de código,entonces lo quito y me sigue dando error.Hay alguna otra solución

Comment: Valida de la forma que indico en mi respuesta! =)

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente la respuesta de Elenasys pero más puritana

1. Elimina esta línea `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)`
2. Cambia `if (Objects.equals(locale, ""))` por `if ("".equals(locale))`